# Pull a specific <TD>'s innertext from webpage/html table

Tags: excel, html-table, vba

I'm trying to pull the innertext to the `<TD>` tag bracketing M118. I was trying to alter this :

```
Range("J" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = IE.Document.getelementbyid("ctl05_BasicdatagridInventoryLocations").getelementbyclass("gridItem").innerText
```

to find the table and row is there something I can add before innertext to select the `<TD>` I'm trying to pull from?

The HTML I'm working with is:

```
<table class="grid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl05_BasicdatagridInventoryLocations" style="border-style:Solid;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">

<tr class="gridPager" align="left">
<td colspan="7"><span>1</span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="gridHeader">
<td>Quantity</td><td>Class</td><td>UOM</td><td>Warehouse</td><td>Location</td><td>Last Cycle Count</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr class="gridItem" onmouseover="cc(this, true);" onmouseout="cc(this, false);">
<td>5</td><td>NEW</td><td>EA</td><td>Rig Warehouse</td><td>M118</td><td>11 Sep 2013</td><td></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this (Tested in IE10):

```
Sub sof20167953GetIeWebpage()
  Dim objIe As Object
  Dim xobj

  Set objIe = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  objIe.Visible = True
  '
  objIe.navigate "http://www.example.com/MyTable.html"
  '
  While (objIe.Busy Or objIe.READYSTATE <> 4)
    DoEvents
  Wend
  '
  Set xobj = objIe.Document.getElementById("ctl05_BasicdatagridInventoryLocations").getElementsByClassName("gridItem").Item(0)
  Set xobj = xobj.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(4)
  '
  Range("J" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = xobj.innerText
  '
  Set xobj = Nothing
  '
  objIe.Quit
  Set objIe = Nothing

End Sub
```

Please notice:

1. getElementById() gets a single element.
2. getElementsByClassName() gets a collection of elements, so use .Item(0) to get first element
3. getElementsByTagName() gets a collection of elements, so use .Item(0) to get first element

Comment: Actually I had it almost done. The mistake that I did was that I was trying it with inbuilt browser and hence I got an error in `Webbrowser1.Document.getElementById("ctl05_BasicdatagridInventoryLocations").getElementsByClassName("gridItem").Item(0)` So i had to divide that in two lines and then use `xobj.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(4)` By the time I figured out my mistake, you had already posted an answer :P

Comment: IE is effectively easier than other method, and more powerful... Not requiring selenium. We have the same solution.

Comment: It's Alive!!
Thank you! Kind of trying to teach myself as I go, hadn't come across the .item() directive in my googling. Thank you again!